# How to display a framebuffer and some stdout text

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, framebuffer

So I have this program that writes to the framebuffer in Ubuntu. It works beautifully: I enter the system terminal using <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then start the program, and it starts writing to the framebuffer and displays its pictures.

However, that program also writes to stdout, which partly obscures the content of the framebuffer. So I start the program and append `>> /dev/tty2`, which sends all the programs' output to the second terminal. I can watch that text by switching to the second terminal using <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Peachy.

However, when I switch back to the first terminal, I don't see the framebuffer any more. Instead, I see the command line that started the program. How can I see the content of the framebuffer instead?